# Time based data

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table called orders, where each row stores an id, a product Id, a sold date, and the number of this product sold for the order in question, as follows:

```
0 101 2011-12-12 2 
1 101 2011-12-12 1
2 101 2011-12-12 1
3 101 2011-12-12 1
4 101 2011-12-11 2
5 101 2011-12-11 1
6 101 2011-12-10 1
7 232 2011-12-10 5
8 101 2011-12-10 1
...
```

How can I query this table so as to get the number of each product sold per day, as follows:

```
101 2011-12-12 5 
232 2011-12-12 0
101 2011-12-11 3
232 2011-12-11 0
101 2011-12-10 2
232 2011-12-10 5
```

And what would one do if the data in question was to be grouped by weeks, months, or years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
select productId, date, sum(qty) as total
from orders
group by productId, date
order by productId
```

Comment: What would I do if I wished to sort the same data by weeks, or months, or  years? Thank!

Comment: You can use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to extract different pieces of information from a column storing temporal data.